# Is there a specific aggregate operation to map superclasses to subclasses?

Tags: java, lambda

Is there a specific aggregate operation to map superclasses to subclasses?

I frequently find myself doing operations such as:

```
list
.stream()
.map((A element) -> (SubClassA) element);
```

Is there an operation that does the equivalent of the `map` function above, that is, takes a `Stream` of values and casts them to a subclass?

Comment: No, such an aggregation function does not exist, because needing this frequently is a sign for bad OOP design. You might want to familiarize yourself with the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @Philipp: Come on :) .NET has exactly these methods in `IEnumerable`: [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) and probably a bit more useful: [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest I can think of is:

```
Stream<X> stream1 = ...
Stream<SubClassA> stream2 = stream1.map(SubClassA.class::cast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generic wirldcard.

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();

Stream<A> streamA1 = list.stream();
Stream<B> streamB1 = (Stream<B>)streamA1;   // ERROR! Cannot cast from Stream<A> to Stream<B>

Stream<? extends A> streamA2 = list.stream();
Stream<B> streamB2 = (Stream<B>)streamA2;   // OK
```